# ChangeReport does not work despite "202 accepted" response

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, app-certification-kit, alexa-smart-home-skill

I'm sending ChangeReport event to Alexa with Postman.
The response looks OK (202 accepted) but the device status doesn't change on the Alexa app or on Alexa developer console state reporter tool.

[Postman request response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAlk6.png)
[State reported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIi3u.png)

However, I can't see the status on the Alexa app. Same thing for the state reporter tool. I tried it last year and have the same problem. I have created a new skill and new account, not working...

I'm trying with this repo [alexa sample change report](https://github.com/alexa-samples/skill-sample-python-send-change-report/tree/main)

It's a big problem because I can't start the "Works with Alexa" certification process if ChangeReport doesn't work.

Thank you for your help !